# Disable statusbar in an activity

Tags: android, android-activity, fullscreen, android-fullscreen

The title says it all: Can I hide and **disable** the statusbar in one activity? In a full screen activity.

I don't want it to show up even if the user touches the top most of the screen.

Can I somehow achieve that?

Answer (score 1):

refer to the link provided by :-
https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/status.html

Comment: All those default methods hide it BUT touching the top of the screen makes it appear again...